# DirectX10/ShapDX Custom control

Tags: directx, direct2d, sharpdx, slimdx

I am trying to create custom control with directx10/direct2D output (panel, not a form). I do all rendering in the overriding OnPaint method, however I have read somewhere that it is wrong and RenderLoop should be used instead. But where should I insert RenderLoop.Run if I can write code only inside of the control? Thank you.

Comment: If you don't need animations, that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You would create a thread, and have RenderLoop.Run inside the thread.  When you do this you have to make sure that events sent back and forth between the components are invoked in a safe manner.